# Don't clear your terminal history 2

Tags: visual, story, knowledge, cipher, geography

[Previously, on terminal use...](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/28516/dont-clear-your-terminal-history)

The door accepted your input and slid open!  Unfortunately, so did a trap door under your feet.  You slide down and end up in another room.  The only apparent exit is a ladder leading up to a locked hatch.  Across the hatch in large, friendly letters are the words <strike>Don't Panic</strike> `Gab Hero`.  Next to the ladder, you see another terminal that reads:

```
> emmrme arrate
Access granted. Door opened.
> higLss geeLeg
Access granted. Door opened.
> gnninn iiinaa
Access granted. Door opened.
> suMsma uuouoo
Access granted. Door opened.
> pfreTT mfpOlA
Access granted. Door opened.
ERROR: ENTRY MISSING! CONTINUING TO NEXT ENTRY
>
```

Looks like it is waiting for your input again...

Hint 1:

> On the wall across from the terminal exists the following poem:
>   `Wonder, wonder where they are?
>   For wondrous things, you'll travel far.`
>   `Where, oh where could they be at?
>   Their position, you know exact.`

Hint 2:

> In an attempt to gather more information from the terminal, you enter the following:
>   `> sudo help`
>   As if in response, the wall next to you slides up, revealing the following image:
>   [image: Wall Image]

Comment: The intro reminds me of Zork or Dungeon, one of the first text adventure games.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think I know the method.

Since the picture is

> Statue of Zeus at Olympia

and that is

> one of the ancient wonders of the world

all of which together

> have locations that spell gab hero:
>  **G**iza
>  **A**lexandria
>  **B**abylon
>  **H**alicarnassus
>  **E**phesus
>  **R**hodes
>  **O**lympia

And I'm pretty sure the ones that have been entered already correspond to

> the first six in order, except Rhodes is skipped

Finally, the passwords are six letters followed by a space, followed by six more letters.

> I wanted this to have to do with longitude and latitude, since Hint 1 tells us we know the "position exact".  <s>But I can't make those numbers correspond with the letters in the title of the Wonder, in order to make a password.</s>  I think I can now, although it makes little sense.

Here's an example:

> #1 is the Great Pyramid of Giza
>  Its longitude and latitude is 29°58′45.03″N 31°08′03.69″E
>  If I translate this to decimal instead, but ignore the decimal part of the seconds, and then round, the longitude and latitude are 29.9792 N and 31.1342 E
>  2, 9, 9, 7, 9, 2 would be wrong, but add 1 to all of them (I guess we are supposed to skip the starting letter)
>  (That is 3, 10, 10, 8, 10, 3)
>  The 3rd letter of "Great Pyramid of Giza" is e
>  The 10th letter is m
>  The 8th letter is r
>  So 3, 10, 10, 8, 10, 3 --> e, m, m, r, m, e
>  and you get emmrme (the first half of the password)
>  same with 3, 1, 1, 3, 4, 2 -- add 1 and you get arrate (the second half of the password)

So for the one you actually need:

> Statue of Zeus at Olympia
>  longitude/latitude is 37°38′16.3″N 21°37′48″E
>  Decimalized as described above is 37.6378 N, 21.63 E
>  Per comment from OP, we need 13 letters, so I'll pad out with zeroes
>  I'm going to guess it's tfotfZ atotSS

So I'm (no longer) stuck.

Comment: I found a different set of numbers at a different site, but I'm not sure which ones to use, so I won't edit yet.

Comment: I'm a little confused. Can you clarify how adding one to each digit in 299792 gives the string of letters?

Comment: Aha! I had gotten stuck after figuring out the poem.. seconding Dan's comment though, I don't understand the numbers -> letters part you did here?

Comment: Ah, gotcha @DaphneB. You're basically using the numbers as 0-indexed coordinates to select a letter from the *name* of the wonder.

Comment: `ERROR: PASSWORD MUST BE 13 CHARACTERS`

Answer (score 1):

I'm no good at ciphers, but I figured out the second hint, if that helps anyone else get started!

> This a depiction of the [Statue of Zeus at Olympia](http://famouswonders.com/statue-of-zeus-at-olympia/):
>  [image: Statue of Zeus at Olympia]

I didn't find any credits for the image, so the image itself must be the clue..

Comment: TinEye knows what this is a picture of.  And that makes me understand "gab hero" but unfortunately it doesn't get me further on the password.