# Don't clear your terminal history 3

Tags: mathematics, pattern, video-games

[Previously, on terminal use...](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/35069/2071)

The door opens and you find yourself in a cave.  After a short walk, you enter a small rectangular area, with a couple of fires towards the far side illuminating the walls, and another terminal between them.  On one side of the terminal is carved what appears to be an `e`.  The other side has a sticker that looks kinda like a scoreboard.  There are no team names given, but the left score is `01` and the right is `67` with a clock in between that shows `39:05`.

[image: scoreboard sticker]

The screen of the terminal displays the following:

```
> cls
Terminal history cleared. Continue with 8th entry
> Manji
Access granted. Door opened.
> Eagle
Access granted. Door opened.
> Lizard
Access granted. Door opened.
> Dragon
Access granted. Door opened.
> Moon
Access granted. Door opened.
> Eagle
Access granted. Door opened.
> Lizard
Access granted. Door opened.
> Dragon
Access granted. Door opened.
> Manji
Access granted. Door opened.
> Snake
Access granted. Door opened.
>
```

Looks like it is waiting for your input again...

Comment: [tag:video-games] hmmm? Interesting

Comment: All of the passwords are used in dungeons in one of the Zelda games (I forget which one). Can't post a full answer right now, but that's a good place to start looking. All the glyphs using different substitutions represent the letters ZELDA in the game, so maybe take the game's name, remove all non-ZELDA letters then enter them in order starting from 8? Just thinking aloud :-)

Comment: @Downvoters care to offer suggestions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe that the answer is

> Dragon

The first thing we need is a mapping to a numerical sequence for the previous entries.

> As noted by Joe in the comments, this is to do with the video game The Legend Of Zelda, where these are the names of some of the levels. The full list of level numbers (zero-based, thank you Sconibulus!) and names, which gives us a mapping is: 
> Eagle 0 
> Moon  1 
> Manji 2 
> Snake 3 
> Lizard 4 
> Dragon 5 
> Demon 6 
> Lion  7 
> Death mountain 8 
> This leads to the sequence 2045104523 for the previous entries.

So how do we get to this sequence? First we note the

> e marked on the side of the terminal. This points us to the mathematical constant e. Starting at the 8th decimal place, as given by the terminal entry, we get the sequence of digits 28459045235.

Then we look at the scoreboard, and note that

> 39 minutes and 5 seconds is 2345 seconds. So reading left to right we get 01234567. These are the digits base 8, so let's apply mod 8 to the digits of e.

This gives us the sequence

> 20451045235, indicating that the next number in the sequence is 5, so the next answer is Dragon.

Comment: If you start numbering the dungeons at 0, rather than 1, then you don't have to add 1, for this line of reasoning

Comment: A hint for the scoreboard, the piece to focus on is the time.  Just for clarification, it's displayed in the standard [minutes]:[seconds]

Comment: "Base 8" doesn't make sense, as 8 would turn into 10. I think mod 8 as you said earlier or something equivalent would be better (I never thought to consider the mathematical constant, nice insight!)